# Convenience init error when updating project from Swift 3

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, initialization

I am updating a project made in Swift 3 and getting the following error now.

> The compiler is unable to type-check this expression in reasonable
>   time; try breaking up the expression into distinct sub-expressions

There is plenty of answers in regards of that error but I don't understand how I am supposed to create sub-expression of the properties in the code below as need the properties together.

```
extension SJTSettings {
convenience init(width: Int? = nil,
                 height: Int? = nil,
                 videoCodec: String? = nil,
                 videoBitrate: Int? = nil,
                 keyframeInterval: Int? = nil,
                 h264Profile: String? = nil,
                 audioCodec: Int? = nil,
                 audioBitrate: Int? = nil)
{

    self.init(properties: [ // where the error warning appears
        "width": width ?? NSNull(),
        "height": height ?? NSNull(),
        "videoCodec": videoCodec ?? NSNull(),
        "videoBitrate": videoBitrate ?? NSNull(),
        "keyframeInterval": keyframeInterval ?? NSNull(),
        "h264Profile": h264Profile ?? NSNull(),
        "audioCodec": audioCodec ?? NSNull(),
        "audioBitrate": audioBitrate ?? NSNull(),
    ])
  }
}
```

Any help or direction would be appreciated, thanks

Comment: How is `init(properties:)` declared? What type of parameter does it take?

Comment: This is caused by the type inference system. To fix this I usually just specify the explicit type of the objects I'm setting.

Comment: With `class SJTSettings { init(properties: [String: Any]) { } }` your code compiles without problems in Xcode 10.2.1.

Comment: Thank you for the help Zonily and Martin. It now makes more sense.

Comment: @STerrier: It still makes no sense to me because you did not provide a [mcve] and I was not able to reproduce the problem.

Comment: Sorry Martin, I wasn't sure how to present this code has isn't mine and didn't understand all of it. I'll try to present it better next time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declaring properties before passing to designated init should help type inference

```
convenience init(width: Int? = nil,
                 height: Int? = nil,
                 videoCodec: String? = nil,
                 videoBitrate: Int? = nil,
                 keyframeInterval: Int? = nil,
                 h264Profile: String? = nil,
                 audioCodec: Int? = nil,
                 audioBitrate: Int? = nil)
{ 
    let properties: [String: Any] = [

           "width": width ?? NSNull(),
           "height": height ?? NSNull(),
           "videoCodec": videoCodec ?? NSNull(),
           "videoBitrate": videoBitrate ?? NSNull(),
           "keyframeInterval": keyframeInterval ?? NSNull(),
           "h264Profile": h264Profile ?? NSNull(),
           "audioCodec": audioCodec ?? NSNull(),
           "audioBitrate": audioBitrate ?? NSNull(),

    ]

    self.init(properties: properties)
}
```